# Magento2 cant find ...min.js

Tags: magento2, javascript

Afer content deploy

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_CH

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

in direcrory `pub/static..../js created ...min.js` files
but magento on frontend try to load not min js
example: 
magento try to load `pub/static/frontend/dv/themeao/de_CH/js/custom-script.js` 
but in directory file has name `custom-script.min.js`

How can i fix it?

Comment: What is the setting in the admin area? To minify or not? Is this is in developer mode or production mode?

Comment: Admin panel is not modify and
enabled developer mode